# import product from csv file

Tags: magento-1.9

here is my file name test2.php
that file have code for the import product, but it has a static data ti insert product, and also have dynamic data, when i select the csv file and import it, csv file data are display but not inserted, 
so how can create it's dynamic?

Here is my code...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
$count = 0;
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
        $csvFile = $_REQUEST['csv_file'];
        $check_sku = $_REQUEST['sku_check'];
        //echo $check_sku;die('ankit');
        if(!empty($csvFile)){
        $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        $firstRow = true;
        $aData = array();
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
          $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
        $temparr = array();
        for($x=1;$x<count($line_of_text);$x++) {
            for($z=0;$z<count($line_of_text[$x]);$z++) {
                if(!in_array($line_of_text[$x][$z],$temparr[$line_of_text[0][$z]]))
                    $temparr[$line_of_text[0][$z]][] = $line_of_text[$x][$z];
            }
        }
        foreach($temparr as $key => $att_value){
            /* Below Condition for Check CSV Header and Add Attribute code Begin */
            if($key == 'Ply Rating / Star Rating'){
                $attr_code = 'ply_rating';
            }else if($key == 'Manufacturer / Brand'){
                $attr_code = 'manufacturer';
            }else if($key == 'New / Used'){
                $attr_code = 'condition';
            }else{
                $attr_code='';
            }
            /* End Attribute Condition */
            $att_value_arr = $att_value;
            foreach($att_value_arr as $sku => $color) {     
                $optionId =  false;
                $attributeCode =  $attr_code;
                if ($color != '') {
                    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
                    if ($attribute->getId() && $attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select') {
                        $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
                                ->setAttribute($attribute)
                                ->getAllOptions(false);
                        $_existValue = false;
                        foreach ($options as $option){
                            if (trim(strtolower($option['label'])) == trim(strtolower($color))) {
                                $_existValue = true;
                                $optionId = $option['value'];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!$_existValue) {
                            $option = array('value' => array('option' => array($color)));
                            $attribute->setData('option', $option);
                            $attribute->save();
                            $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
                                    ->setAttribute($attribute)
                                    ->getAllOptions(false);
                            foreach ($options as $option) {
                                if (trim(strtolower($option['label'])) == trim(strtolower($color))) {
                                    $optionId = $option['value'];
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ** echo "<pre>";
        print_r($line_of_text);die(); **    **//Print The Excel Sheet Data**

        /************************* Below Code for IMPORT a Product Begin ***************************/
        function getUniqueCode($length = "")
        {
            $code = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            if ($length != "") return substr($code, 0, $length);
            else return $code;
        }

        /********************** Below Code is check if SKU is exist or not Below *******************/
        $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->load();
            // ARRAY For Get All Product SKU
            $arr_sku = array();
            foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
                $arr_sku[] = $_product->getSku();
            }

        /* $check_sku_is_found = array_search("TR-007 MFT-6121",$arr_sku);
            if(!empty($check_sku_is_found)){
                echo $check_sku_is_found;
            }else{
                echo "Value not found";
            }
        if($check_sku == 'update'){
            echo "update";die();
        }else{
            echo "skip";die();
        } */


        /********************** Below Code is check if SKU is exist or not End ********************/
            $data = array(); // This Code Actually Import Product
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
                $randomString = getUniqueCode(20);
                $data[] = array(
                    'sku' => $i,
                    '_type' => 'simple',
                    '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
                    '_product_websites' => 'base',
                    '_category' => 'otrtires',
                    'manufacturer' => 'Apolo',
                    'name' => 'My Test Product',        
                    'price' => 0.99,        
                    'special_price' => 0.90,
                    'cost' => 0.50,
                    'description' => 'Default',
                    'short_description' => 'Default',
                    'meta_title' => 'Default',
                    'meta_description' => 'Default',
                    'meta_keyword' => 'Default',
                    'weight' => 11,
                    'status' => 1,
                    'visibility' => 4,
                    'tax_class_id' => 2,
                    'qty' => 0,
                    'is_in_stock' => 1,
                    'enable_googlecheckout' => '1',
                    'gift_message_available' => '0',
                    'url_key' => '',
                );

            }
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $time = microtime(true);

            try {
                /** @var $import AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import */
                $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
                $import->processProductImport($data);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
            }
        $suc_err = "Product Import Successfully !!";
        echo 'Elapsed time: ' . round(microtime(true) - $time, 2) . 's' . "\n";

        /************************* Below Code for IMPORT a Product End *****************************/
    }else{
        $msg_err = "Please Select CSV file";
    }
//print_r($temparr);
fclose($file_handle);
}
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
//verify if the user is logged in to the backend
    if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        ?>
        <div class="csv_import">
            <div class="csv_wrapper">
            <center>
                <h3>Upload Your Product CSV</h3>
                <span style="color:red !important;"><?php if (isset($msg_err)) echo $msg_err; ?>
                <span style="color:green !important;"><?php if (isset($suc_err)) echo $suc_err; ?>
            </center>
            <div class="csv_import_form">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
                    <input type="file" accept=".csv" name="csv_file"></input>
                    <label>If SKU is Found ? :</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="rad_box" name="sku_check" value="update" checked>Update
                    <input type="radio" class="rad_box" name="sku_check" value="skip"> Skip<br>
                    <input class="btn default" type="submit" name="submit" value="IMPORT"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else{ ?>
        <div class="csv_import_form">
            <h1>Admin User is Not Login</h1>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    background:#222D3F;
}
.csv_import{width:100%;height:100%;color:#fff;}
.btn {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8%;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  margin-top:15px;
}
.default {background-color: #e7e7e7; color: black;} /* Gray */
.default:hover {background: #ddd;}
.csv_import_form {
  width: 38%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 2%;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.csv_wrapper {
  padding: 16% 0;
}
form {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: excel sheet data print in variable $line_of_text How to imports its to dynamic way?